# Powershell in UIPath. Throw : Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.GetItemResponse' to type 'System.String'

Tags: powershell, invoke, exchange-server-2010, uipath

I am trying to grab emails from Exchange using powershell in UI Path. When trying to return the items, I get the following error:

> Throw : Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.GetItemResponse' to type 'System.String'.

Even when I change the TypeArgument in UI Path. Currently I am using the Invoke power shell activity but I get the same issues using the RunPowershellScript activity. Below is a screenshot of my sequence in UI Path, my parameters, and my powershell script, Thank you!

[image: Ui path Screenshot]

[image: UI Path Parameters]

```
Param(
[parameter()]
[string]$mailbox,

[parameter()]
[string]$password
)
try{
#https://forum.uipath.com/t/get-argument-from-an-process-with-exception-in-reframework/22537/4
function test-password(){
                $Creds = new-object System.Net.networkCredential -ArgumentList $mailbox, $password

                $mailFolder = "Inbox"
                $itemView = 3

                #[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll")
                $ExSer = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP1)
                $ExSer.Credentials = ($Creds)
                $ExSer.Url = new-object Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")
                $ExSer.AutodiscoverUrl($mailbox, {$true})


                $setMailFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($ExSer,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)
                $logs2 += "Successfully Connected to mailbox $mailbox"

                $iv = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView($itemView)

                $CustomFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+SearchFilterCollection([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LogicalOperator]::And)

                $ifIsRead = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::IsRead,$false)
                $ifFrom = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::From,"filteremail@mycompany.com")

                $CustomFilter.add($ifIsRead)
                $CustomFilter.add($ifFrom)

                $filteredEmails = $ExSer.FindItems($setMailFolder.Id,$CustomFilter, $iv)

                $psPropertySet = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
                $psPropertySet.RequestedBodyType = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType]::Text;
                #add-type "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.GetItemResponse"
                $ExSer.LoadPropertiesForItems($filteredEmails,$psPropertySet)

                $item = $filteredEmails.Items[0]

                return $mailbox, $item
    }               


   test-password
}
catch{
        Throw
}
```

I commented out the load dll as it seemed to work without it and was throwing a similar error when it hit it. The code seems to throw an error when it hits $Exser.LoadPropertyItems. I have also tried switching to Exchange 2007 etc. To clarify, when running purely powershell outside of UI Path, this code works just fine.

Comment: As error says it expectets string but getting differen5 type? What is in  filtereditems?

Comment: I assume it is an email object utilizing this type Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.GetItemResponse

Comment: or a list of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out....I was just being a dingus. It was trying to load an object, which was breaking it. If I saved it as a variable and then converted it within my script and returned what I needed as a string....guess what? It could understand the string. Below is my updated powershell.

```
 Param(
[parameter()]
[string]$mailbox,

[parameter()]
[string]$password
)
try{
#https://forum.uipath.com/t/get-argument-from-an-process-with-exception-in-reframework/22537/4
function test-password(){

                $Creds = new-object System.Net.networkCredential -ArgumentList $mailbox, $password

                $mailFolder = "Inbox"
                $itemView = 50

               # Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
                #[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.2\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll")
                $ExSer = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion]::Exchange2010_SP1)
                $ExSer.Credentials = ($Creds)
                $ExSer.Url = new-object Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx")
                $ExSer.AutodiscoverUrl($mailbox, {$true})


                $setMailFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($ExSer,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox)
                $logs2 += "Successfully Connected to mailbox $mailbox"

                $iv = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView($itemView)

                $CustomFilter = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+SearchFilterCollection([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.LogicalOperator]::And)

                $ifIsRead = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::IsRead,$true)
                $ifFrom = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SearchFilter+IsEqualTo([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessageSchema]::From,"emailtofilterby@mycompany.com")

                $CustomFilter.add($ifIsRead)
                $CustomFilter.add($ifFrom)

                $filteredEmails = $ExSer.FindItems($setMailFolder.Id,$CustomFilter, $iv)

                $psPropertySet = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
                $psPropertySet.RequestedBodyType = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType]::Text;
                #add-type "Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.GetItemResponse"
                $FilteredEmailitems = $ExSer.LoadPropertiesForItems($filteredEmails,$psPropertySet) 


                $EmailBody = $FilteredEmailitems.Item(0) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Item | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Body | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Text

                return $EmailBody
    }               


   test-password
}
catch{
        Throw
}
```